# How to move a "li" element to nth position from current on each click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-calculation

How to move a "li" element to nth position from current on each click of a button?

In the below example, on each click of button, we have to move the 3rd li to 7th(3+4)  position on 1st click, to  11th(7+4) position on 2nd click, to 15th(11+4) on 3rd and so on.

I've attached code snippet. And it is working for first click.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").on('click', function(){
  $(".active").insertAfter("li:nth-child(7)");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>move</button>
    <ul>
    <li>1st list item</li>
    <li>2nd list item</li>
    <li class="active">3rd list item</li>
    <li>4th list item</li>
    <li>5th list item</li>
    <li>6th list item</li>
    <li>7th list item</li>
    <li>8th list item</li>
    <li>9th list item</li>
    <li>10th list item</li>
    <li>11th list item</li>
    <li>12th list item</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: No see no attempts at solving this what so ever. Where is your code?

Comment: Put some efforts into it, If you get stuck, Show us the effort and ask question from that. That would be the right way.

Comment: provide us with some snippets to help you

Comment: So select the element, and insert it at the new location.

Comment: @vishnu You should familiarize yourself with jQuery and very, very, very basic HTML/JavaScript before you ask a question like this. SO will not answer questions like this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be helpful

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var cnt=3;
$("button").on('click', function(){
  cnt+=4;
  $(".active").insertAfter("li:nth-child("+cnt+")");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>move</button>
    <ul>
    <li>1st list item</li>
    <li>2nd list item</li>
    <li class="active">3rd list item</li>
    <li>4th list item</li>
    <li>5th list item</li>
    <li>6th list item</li>
    <li>7th list item</li>
    <li>8th list item</li>
    <li>9th list item</li>
    <li>10th list item</li>
    <li>11th list item</li>
    <li>12th list item</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
$("button").on('click', function(){
  $(".active").nextAll('li').eq(3).after($('.active'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>move</button>
    <ul>
    <li>1st list item</li>
    <li>2nd list item</li>
    <li class="active">3rd list item</li>
    <li>4th list item</li>
    <li>5th list item</li>
    <li>6th list item</li>
    <li>7th list item</li>
    <li>8th list item</li>
    <li>9th list item</li>
    <li>10th list item</li>
    <li>11th list item</li>
    <li>12th list item</li>
    </ul>
```